# Laravel 6 Unit Testing Responses 401

Tags: api, unit-testing, testing, laravel-6

I am using Token based operations. The request for the Edit operation in Project works well in Postman.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $project = Project::find($id);
        $project->project_name = request('project_name');
        $project->project_description = request('project_description');
        $project->save();
        return response()->json([
            'message' =>  "Project Updated Successfully",
            'updatedId' => $project->id
            ], 200);
    }
```

But in Unit Testing Not getting Proper Responses

```
 public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $response = $this->withHeaders([
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOi......'
        ])->json('POST', '/api/updateProject/1',
                ['project_name' => 'Sally'],
                ['project_description' => 'testing the api']
                );

                $response->assertStatus(200);
                $response->assertJson(['status' => true]);
    }
```

Error Shows

```
PS D:\XMAPP\htdocs\minidmsapi> ./vendor/bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 8.4.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

..F.                                                                4 / 4 (100%)

Time: 516 ms, Memory: 18.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Modules\Projects\Tests\Unit\ProjectTest::testupdate
Expected status code 200 but received 401.
Failed asserting that false is true.

D:\XMAPP\htdocs\minidmsapi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse.php:166
D:\XMAPP\htdocs\minidmsapi\Modules\Projects\Tests\Unit\ProjectTest.php:35

FAILURES!
Tests: 4, Assertions: 4, Failures: 1.
```

Why Unit Testing having Error Response 401 ?

Kindly anyone, please explain to me What is the actual error in unit testing and solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing

```
['project_description' => 'testing the api']
```

to the `$headers` of the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests::json()` call:

```
public function json($method, $uri, array $data = [], array $headers = [])
```

which is causing your `Authorization` header to get overwritten.

I think you mean to pass the combination of your 3rd and 4th param as the 3rd.

```
$response = $this->withHeaders([
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOi......'
    ])
    ->json(
        'POST', 
        '/api/updateProject/1',
        [
            'project_name' => 'Sally',
            'project_description' => 'testing the api'
        ]
    );
```

Comment: I tried with your Code. But ```$response->assertStatus(200);
                $response->assertJson(['status' => true]); ``` By this code same error appers. !!!

Comment: Any solutions ?